# How to keep the distance between $n$ particles within a certain range?

Tags: algorithm, fortran, graph-algorithm, fortran90, fortran77

I am working on a problem in Molecular Dynamics and need to randomly generate a position array for np particles within a box of size [-L,L] x [-L,L]. In fact, I need to generate the x-array for the x-coordinates with x(1) = 0 and the y-array for the y-coordinates with y(1)=y(2) =0. I need the particles to be such that the distances between neighboring particles are within some range (e.g: 0.9 <= r <= 1.1) like in the following picture:
[image]

However in my code I get something like this:
[image]

See how the red lines are larger than what I want.

My code is

```
REAL, DIMENSION(np) :: x, y
REAL :: w1, w2, minv, maxv, xij, yij, rij
INTEGER :: i, j

!Generating random coordinates for the particles
x(1) = 0.0d0
y(1) = 0.0d0
y(2) = 0.0d0
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
! translation and rotaion of the whole system were froze (saving 4 degrees of
! freedome)
! x(1) = 0.0d0; y(1) = 0.0d0    fix one particle in the origin
! y(2) = 0.0d0              fix the second particle on the x-axis
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------

rmatrix = 100.0
minv = 0.0
maxv = 10
iter0 = 0
101 DO WHILE(maxv >= 1.1 .OR. minv <= 0.9) 
iter0 = iter0 + 1
PRINT *, iter0
    CALL init_random_seed()
    DO i = 2, np
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(w1)
        x(i) = 10 * w1 - 5
    END DO
    DO i = 3, np
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(w2)
        y(i) = 10 * w2 - 5
    END DO
! rmatrix contains the distances between all particles 
    DO i = 1, np
        DO j = 1, np
            IF(j .NE. i) THEN
                xij = x(i) - x(j)
                yij = y(i) - y(j)
                rij = SQRT(xij * xij + yij * yij)
                rmatrix(i,j) = rij
            END IF
        END DO
    END DO
    minv = MINVAL(rmatrix) ! This is the minimum distance between any two 
                          ! particles ( distance cannot be smaller)
                          ! which is the left endpoint of the range interval
    DO i = 1, np     ! Here is my attempt to control the righ endpoint of          
        DO j = 1, np  ! the range interval. ( This needs to be edited)
            IF(j .NE. i) THEN
                maxv = MIN(maxv, rmatrix(i,j))
            END IF
        END DO
        IF(maxv >= 1.1) THEN
            GOTO 101
        END IF
    END DO
END DO

CONTANIS
      SUBROUTINE init_random_seed()
        INTEGER :: i, n, clock
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: seed

        CALL RANDOM_SEED(size = n)
        ALLOCATE(seed(n))

        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(COUNT=clock)

        seed = clock + 37 * (/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)

        CALL RANDOM_SEED(PUT = seed)

      END SUBROUTINE init_random_seed
```

Comment: you need distance range between all the particles o just between some of them? The wanted image suggest the later in that case what are the rules?

Comment: Not sure I get exactly what you want, for instance could you define "neighbouring" please? And the above isn't your code, please show the variable declarations, they are important! If you really want help it is best to show what you are actually compiling and running. Finally why can't you just set up a regular lattice with the spacing between the particles the middle of the range you want and then perturb that slightly?

Comment: @Spektre If you pick a particle then the distance between this particle and its nearest neighbors is in the range e.g. (0.8, 1.2).

Comment: @IanBush What am doing is generating random positions for number of particles, say 10, then apply some numerical schemes to find their potential minimum, or in other words, how their configuration will look like. 
This is my code, see the edited code above.

Comment: For example let np = 7 particles, then if their initial positions are as in the first picture ( i.e., the distances between each particle and it nearest neighbors are within some range) then this system has 4 possible configurations and one of them looks like a hexagon with 6 particles on the vertices and one particle in the middle of it (Hard to graph it in the comment)

Comment: Your formulation of the problem isn't very clear. Do you mean all the edges of a Delaunay triangulation of the vertices are within the given bracket?  Getting a truly random distribution within this constraint is likely to be extremely difficult. A possible way is to generate way too many random points, construct a triangulation (say with the GNU triangulated surface library http://gts.sourceforge.net/), and then remove edges (or maybe one of the endpoints of such edges) that are too short and re-triangulate until all the edges are within the bracket (and hopefully none are too long).

Comment: @Ruzayqat you need to introduce some rules or connectivity info otherwise how to decide which points are close or not? Current description is resulting in "uniformly" distributed points with average distance = 1.0 from each other. If you want to achieve molecule configuration you need to add info which point is connected to how many other points and generate accordingly.